# Combining two list to make a dictionary

Tags: python

I need to convert two list into a dictionary. I have two list named A and B,

A = [[1,2,3] [2,3,4] [1,4,5] [1,3,4]]

the values in A (list of list) will be unique

B = [[10,13,23] [22,21,12] [5,34,23] [10,9,8]]

the length of both list will be same

I need the result like

C = [['1' :10 , '2' :13, '3': 23] ['2':22, '3':21, '4':12] ['1':5, '4':34, '5':23] ['1':10, '3':9, '4':8]]

I tried the dict method but it is throwing me an error saying list is un hashable type. Please let me know how to do this. Im new to python.

Comment: Your inputs aren't valid lists, because there are no commas between the sub-lists. Your output isn't a valid anything, because dicts go in curly braces, and lists don't have colons. Also, don't just vaguely describe your code and the error message, copy and paste the actual code and error.

Comment: @abarnert My input has comma in between sub list, while typing here I missed it. The output has to be dictionary of the sub lists.

Comment: Don't type it here, copy and paste from actual running code that demonstrates your question. And again, don't _describe_ your output, show the actual output you want. "dictionary of the sub lists" doesn't make sense, and it also doesn't match what's in your question. We can try to _guess_ what you have and what you want, but most people are going to guess wrong most of the time, because we're only so smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure, but I'm guessing your problem is this:

If `a` and `b` were just flat lists of numbers, all you'd have to do is this:

```
dict(zip(a, b))
```

And I'm assuming that's similar to what you wrote. But that doesn't work here. Those aren't lists of numbers, they're list of lists. And you don't to get back a dict, you want a list of dicts.

So, you're asking Python to create a dict whose keys are the sub-lists of `a`, and whose values are the sub-lists of `b`. That's an error because lists can't be keys, but it wouldn't be useful even if that weren't an issue.

To actually do this, you need to not only `zip` up `a` and `b`, but also zip up their sublists, and pass those sub-zips, not the main zip, to `dict`. Like this:

```
[dict(zip(suba, subb)) for (suba, subb) in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: I just have one more doubt which is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: @user3559583: Efficient in what sense? If you mean speed, it's unlikely to ever matter in any real program, so that's the last thing you should be worrying about here; worry about being able to understand the code, expand on it, etc., or reducing the number of places where you have to repeat yourself or where you could introduce a subtle bug; anything but efficiency.

Comment: @user3559583: But if your program is too slow and you profile it and discover that this conversion is too slow, and you can't remove the conversion so you need to micro-optimize it… in that case, I'd bet this is pretty close to optimal. You pretty much have to do this much looping, and doing all of it inside the interpreter and builtin functions is almost always faster than doing it in `for` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want C to be a list of dictionaries. Here's a straightforward way to do that.

```
def combine(keys, values):
    "generate a dictionary from keys and values"
    out = {}
    for k,v in zip(keys,values):
       out[k] = v
    return out

def combine_each(keys, values):
    "for each pair of keys and values, make a dictionary"
    return [combine(klist, vlist) for (klist,vlist) in zip(keys,values)]

C = combine_each(A,B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
>>> A = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [1,4,5], [1,3,4]]
>>> B = [[10,13,23], [22,21,12], [5,34,23], [10,9,8]]
>>> [{k:v for k, v in zip(sa, sb)} for (sa, sb) in zip(A, B)]
[{1: 10, 2: 13, 3: 23}, {2: 22, 3: 21, 4: 12}, {1: 5, 4: 34, 5: 23}, {1: 10, 3: 9, 4: 8}]
```